# What do "support" and "resistance" mean?

Tags: trading, terminology

I'm still very much a newbie to all this and would like to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

By 'support' and 'resistance' assume you mean in the context of trading an asset. If so, then, simplistically, support means a level at which the value of the asset could become attractive for incremental buyers. Resistance means the value which the asset may be having a hard time breaking out of (likely due to people selling at those levels)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am still very new to this and would like to learn more. I was trying to search videos youtube about it but there were so many to sift through so I figured I should just ask. Thank you!